# using $.when to execute first ajax then execute the next in $.when().done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know this has been asked multiple times but I'm having a problem executing `$.ajax` by order using `$.when`.

In the sample code below, I want to run the first ajax inside `$.when()` then the second `$.ajax` inside `.done()`.

```
var api = {
    getFoo: function(callback) {
        $.when(this.getBar()).done(function() {
            chrome.storage.local.get(['bar'], function(data) {
                // omitted some code here for brevity
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: /api/foo/,
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function(result) {
                    console.log('success', 'went here!');
                }).fail(function(request) {
                    console.log('failed', 'went here!');
                });
            });
        });
    },
    getBar: function() {
        chrome.storage.local.get(['data1'], function(data) {

            if(typeof data['data1'] !== 'undefined') {
                // omitted some code here for brevity
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: /api/bar/,
                    data: data['data1'],
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function(result) {
                    console.log('success', 'went here!');
                }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log('failed', 'went here!');
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I ran the code, the second `$.ajax` execute immediately without waiting for the first `$.ajax` to finish. Please, could anyone redirect me to the right way?

Comment: `$.when` expects promises as arguments,  `this.getBar()` does not return a promise... it doesn't return anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to return a promise for async actions
try this:

```
getFoo: function(callback) {
    this.getBar().then(function(){
        chrome.storage.local.get(['bar'], function(data) {
            // omitted some code here for brevity
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: /api/foo/,
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(result) {
                console.log('success', 'went here!');
            }).fail(function(request) {
                console.log('failed', 'went here!');
            });
        });
    });
},
getBar: function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    chrome.storage.local.get(['data1'], function(data) {
        if(typeof data['data1'] !== 'undefined') {
            // omitted some code here for brevity
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: /api/bar/,
                data: data['data1'],
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example at [jQuery - when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) page. Here is a short example:

```
var api = {
    flag: $.Deferred(),
    getFoo: function(callback) {
        $.when(this.flag).done(function() {
            console.log('getFoo');
        });
    },
    getBar: function() {
        console.log('getBar');
        this.flag.resolve();
    }
}
```